# Ava separate integration and unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, npm, integration-testing, package.json, ava

I'd like to use 'ava' tool for both unit and integration testing.  But I can't figure out what's the best way to separate those tests.  Unit tests should run before the code deployed into test environment, and integration tests need to run after the code has been deployed to the test server.

My challenge is that 'ava' reads it's configuration from 'ava' section of `package.json`.  Not sure how to tell it to use different sets of test sources depending on which stage of deployment it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use an `ava.config.js` file. For now, you could use environment variables to switch the config. Keep an eye on https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1857 though which will add a CLI flag so you can select a different config file.